# How do I execute an event using jQuery through an html object(button) created through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just new here.  So here's where I'm stuck:

I created an html table using javascript.  I have a button,which when clicked, will create set of tables with exactly the same structure but the objects(eg. button, text) inside those tables have different ID's.  Now when I try to execute a click function using jQuery with a button on one of the produced tables, it won't work.  How do I go around here? Thanks in advance!

Here's a sample function which creates the html table(with unique ID's) in javascript:

```
function CreateTables() {

    var html = ' ';
    var valPrompt = prompt("How many tables would you like to add?");
    parseInt(valPrompt);
    for (i = 1; i <= valPrompt; i++) {

        html += "<table>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Text goes here" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<input type='text' id='txtTEXT" + i + "'/>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + < input type = 'button'
        id = 'btnALERT" + i + "' / > +"</td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>"
    }
    document.getElementById('HtmlPlaceHolder').innerHTML = html;
}​
```

So, if we review the code, Sets of table with buttons(btnALERT) with unique ID's will be created if the function **CreateTables** is executed.  In order to select the objects, I suppose I'll be using jQuery.  So for example, if I bind a handler in btnALERT1(produced by CreateTables) say a click function in order to alert a simple "Hello", how will I do this? My code for this doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnALERT1').click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});​
```

Comment: your valPrompt value is still a string, you should save it to a variable. valPrompt = parseInt(valPrompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (for older jquery versions - < v1.7):

```
$('#btnALERT1').live('click', function()
{
   alert("Hello");
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).delegate('#btnALERT1', 'click', function() 
{
   alert("Hello");
});
```

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (for new jquery versions - >= 1.7):

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnALERT1', function()
{
   alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use the method `.on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnALERT1').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

For more information, check the online doc: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the event handlers after you create the tables, not when the document is ready (the document should be ready anyways since the user is interacting with it).

You can do this with jQuery, sure, but have a look at the native methods - jQuery might be too bloated depending on what you will do and you will learn something about the DOM.

I've added some code below which lets you add a callback and shows some things you can get back easily. It is not exactly what you asked for, but a great start to finding your way in the DOM.

```
function CreateTables() {

    var html = ' ';
    var valPrompt = prompt("How many tables would you like to add?");
    parseInt(valPrompt);
    for (i = 1; i <= valPrompt; i++) {

        html += "<table>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Text goes here" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<input type='text' id='txtTEXT" + i + "'/>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + < input type = 'button'
        id = 'btnALERT" + i + "' / > +"</td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>"
    }
    var placeholder = document.getElementById('HtmlPlaceHolder').innerHTML = html;
    placeholder.innerHTML = html;
    placeholder.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       console.log(this, e);
    }

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a delegate on HtmlPlaceHolder to check for click events like so:

```
$("#HtmlPlaceHolder").on("click", "input[type=button]", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Also, I would change the button id scheme to btnALERT_1, so you can extract the ID number with a `.split("_")` method.